# What will my LGPS pension refund consist of?

Tags: united-kingdom, pension

I have recently changed jobs. My previous pension was with Scottish Widows and contributions were done through salary sacrifice. I now have a LGPS (Local Government Pension Scheme) pension and have the option to transfer my old pension into it. I haven't done so yet.

I have been contributing for about 3 months now and things are difficult financially and could use extra money. As I have not been with LGPS for 2 years, if I opt out, I can claim a contribution refund.

If I were to transfer my Sottish Widows pension into LGPS then claimed a refund, what would the refund consist of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you transfer another pension into the LGPS, the 2 year vesting period may not apply depending on your circumstances relating to the transferred scheme. As a result it is unlikely you would be able to simply exit the scheme and extract the contributions made elsewhere, especially if you weren’t able to do so in your previous scheme.

https://lgpsmember.org/more/vesting.php